# Highlight Duplicate word on hover using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I have the following html

```
<div class="my-div">
     <p>
        Hello from the moon        
     </p>
</div>
<div class="my-div">
     <p>
        Hello World
     </p>
</div>
```

Is it possible using javascript that when I hover on the word 'Hello' in the first div, I highlight or even bold just the 'Hello' word in the second div..

Any help appreciated

Comment: You would need to put a span or some other tag about the word that you want to highlight, in order to highlight it specifically

Comment: You mean that you want to hover any 'hello' word in each divs?!?! @rogger2016

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight a specific word you need to place it in `<span>` tag. For example:

```
 <div class="my-div">
        <p>
            <span class="first-hello">Hello</span> from the moon        
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="my-div">
        <p>
            <span class="second-hello">Hello</span> World
        </p>
    </div>
```

In JavaScript file, you can select your elements by using `document.querySelector()` function. And then add appropriate event listeners, in this case, `mousemove` that is fired when a mouse is moved while the cursor is inside the element, and `mouseout` that is fired when the cursor is moved outside of the element

```
const firstHello = document.querySelector(".first-hello");
const secondHello = document.querySelector(".second-hello");

firstHello.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
    secondHello.style.fontWeight = "bold";
});

firstHello.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    secondHello.style.fontWeight = "normal";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Lettering.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/blob/master/jquery.lettering.js) and `Jquery` to achieve this.

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"</script>
<script src="lettering.js"></script>

<script>
function btnClicked(){

 //The words are now put into individual spans. See lettering js documentation
 $(".lettr").lettering('words');

 $("span").hover(function(e){

    // set default background color to white
    $("span").css("background-color", "white");

    //Get the word at the current mouse hover
    let word = e.target.innerHTML.trim();
    //Keep a list of all spans in the html document
    let listSpans = $("html").find("span");

    //Loop through all the individual spans and see if the innerHTML matches the word. If so , highlight it.
    for(let i=0;i<listSpans.length;i++){
        let spanword= listSpans[i].innerHTML.trim();

        if(spanword== word){
            $(listSpans[i]).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
    }
    }, function (e) {

  });

}
</script>
```

Here is my body

```
<body>
<div>
    <p class="lettr"> Heloo i am </p>
    <p class="lettr">Heloo me too</p>
</div>

<button onClick="btnClicked();">Click me</button>
</body>
```